# addAttributeOption intger value not add in database using code

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, sql

I have try to addAttributeOption() integer value add in database using my code.

But i have facing on error message when i have add integer value in CSV

(1) Not Working CSV:-
70024,70014,70010,70624,70040,70017,70014,70010

(2) Working CSV:-
A550-24,B55014,C55010,D94624,E75040,F75017,G75014,H75010,I55334

**Error message is** 
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

My part of code is

foreach
($attribute_arr as $key=>$value)
{

```
        $option['value'][$value][0]=$value;

        foreach($allStores as $skey =>$svalue){

            $option['value'][$value][$skey] = $value;

        }

    }
```

$eavSetup = $this->_eavSetupFactory->create();

$eavSetup->addAttributeOption($option);

Comment: Can you post the full code that you're using?

Answer (score 0):

You have `70014` and `70010` twice in your array

Comment: This should be in the comment section. Please avoid one line answers and try to explain as much as possible.